# I want to calculate the occurrences of each number in aray in Dart

Tags: function, dart

i have that needs me to make a function that counts the occurrences of each number in an array `[2,5,6,6,8,4,2,5,2]` and print it like this
2 -> 3 times
6 -> 2 times and so on
I did it before but it was to count the occurrences of one number not all of them so can anyone help ... Thanks in advance

to update this is the code I used to count the occurrences of one number

```dart
int countTwo(List<int> arr, int value) {
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == value) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

void main() {
  List<int> arr = [5, 6, 15, 2, 8, 2, 38, 2];
  int x = countTwo(arr, 2);
  print(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set from list to get unique int.

```dart
final data = [2, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2, 5, 2];
final dataSet = data.toSet();

int counter(int number) {
  final int counter = data.where((element) => element == number).length; //you can use for loop here too
  return counter;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  print(
      "number ${dataSet.elementAt(i)} -> ${counter(dataSet.elementAt(i))} times");
}
```

And with your method just do

```dart
final data = [2, 5, 6, 6, 8, 4, 2, 5, 2];
final dataSet = data.toSet();

for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  final checkNUmber = dataSet.elementAt(i);
  print("number $checkNUmber->  ${countTwo(data, checkNUmber)} times");
}
```

Result

```
number 2 -> 3 times
number 5 -> 2 times
number 6 -> 2 times
number 8 -> 1 times
number 4 -> 1 times
```

Comment: Final ,toSet() and elementAt() , what those do exactly

Comment: `toSet()` creating a set from list containing unique ite, and `elementAt` is used to get item from set. more About [Set](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.2/dart-core/Set-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a map to collect the count:

```dart
var count = <int, int>{};
for (var n in data) {
  count[n] = (count[n] ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

After that, you have all the individual elements, and the number of times it occurred:

```dart
for (var n in count.keys) {
  print("$n: ${count[n]} times");
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is a map, sorry new to dart and programming.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the Dart language tour. Maps are discussed here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps